# Unix C - Compiling for 64 bit breaks "dirname"

Tags: c, unix, gcc, 64-bit, dirname

I'm using dirname from libgen.h to get the directory path from a filename's path.

This is it's signature:

```
char * dirname (char *path)
```

When compiling on a 32 bit machine or using -m32 with gcc, it all works fine.

My code looks like this:

```
char* path = "/path/to/my/file.txt";
char* path_cpy = strdup(path);
const char* dir = (const char*)dirname(path_cpy);
```

If I compile on a 64 bit machine, I get the warning:

```
"warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size"
```

This will fix the warning, but crashes at runtime:

```
const char* dir = (const char*)(uintptr_t)dirname(path_cpy);
```

I have never tried to cross compile for 32/64 bit before, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you including the header file that includes the definition for `dirname` (that's `libgen.h` on my system, check in `/usr/include`)?

The warning `"cast to pointer from integer of different size"` sounds like it's casting from an `int`, the default return code from functions with no prototype defined.

It's likely that what's happening is that your `int` and `char *` data types are the same size for 32-bit code but, when you switch over to 64 bits, they're actually different sizes.

You could verify this by printing out `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char*)` and seeing if they're different.

Comment: You are correct, this fixed my issue.  I understand why it would break on 64 bit.

Comment: What I don't get is why you didn't have, somewhere in your comile output, something like `Undefined reference to dirname()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have failed to provide a prototype for `dirname` (either by including `libgen.h` or prototyping it yourself), so it implicitly get type `int dirname();`. Since this does not match the actual function, your program has undefined behavior. (In this case, the upper half of the pointer gets truncated.)